# How to add a widget to the post editing view?

Tags: plugin-development, metabox, editor

I would like to add some features (via authoring a plugin) to the post editor in wordpress.  Is there a way to add a widget to the post editor view?

Alternatively is there an existing plugin someone can point me too, that does this so I can see how they do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Widgets" as you're calling them on the post edit screen are actually meta boxes.  You can add as many as you want to do whatever you want using the [`add_meta_box()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) function.

Once you know what they're called, it's fairly straight-forward to do a Google search for examples.  Or check out some great tutorials listed in the Codex.

Comment: thanx that solved it!